# How to form correct JQ Expression to get exact output data from JSON file?

Tags: json, jq

I am using JQ Play.

Here is my JSON Data -

```json
{
  "body": {
    "name": "DATATYPES",
    "primarykey": [
      "db_number"
    ],
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "db_number",
        "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_date",
        "type": "DATE"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_timestamp",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP(6)"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_char",
        "type": "CHAR"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_float",
        "type": "FLOAT"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_nchar",
        "type": "NCHAR"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_nvarchar2",
        "type": "NVARCHAR2"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_varchar2",
        "type": "VARCHAR2"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_binary_float",
        "type": "BINARY_FLOAT"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_binary_double",
        "type": "BINARY_DOUBLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_timestamp_with_time_zone",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_interval_year_to_month",
        "type": "INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_interval_day_to_second",
        "type": "INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_long",
        "type": "LONG"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_blob",
        "type": "BLOB"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_clob",
        "type": "CLOB"
      },
      {
        "name": "db_boolean",
        "type": "CHAR"
      }
    ],
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "collection",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/",
        "mediaType": "application/json"
      },
      {
        "rel": "canonical",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/metadata-catalog/datatypes/",
        "mediaType": "application/json"
      },
      {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/open-api-catalog/datatypes/",
        "mediaType": "application/openapi+json"
      },
      {
        "rel": "describes",
        "href": "https://tdcvm28s16.bcone.com:7002/ords/testords/datatypes/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My JQ -

```js
{parameters: (.body.primarykey[] | {(.): ""}), body: (.body.members | map({(.name): .type |ascii_downcase}) | add)}
```

Output -

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "db_number": ""
  },
  "body": {
    "db_number": "number",
    "db_date": "date",
    "db_timestamp": "timestamp(6)",
    "db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with local time zone",
    "db_char": "char",
    "db_float": "float",
    "db_nchar": "nchar",
    "db_nvarchar2": "nvarchar2",
    "db_varchar2": "varchar2",
    "db_binary_float": "binary_float",
    "db_binary_double": "binary_double",
    "db_timestamp_with_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with time zone",
    "db_interval_year_to_month": "interval year(2) to month",
    "db_interval_day_to_second": "interval day(2) to second(6)",
    "db_long": "long",
    "db_blob": "blob",
    "db_clob": "clob",
    "db_boolean": "char"
  }
}
```

Here, my requirement is - I want to remove record / field from output `body:{}` which is having same name as `primarykey`.

So I am not able to form such JQ that will not fetch matching record with `primarykey` inside body.

My expected output is -

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "db_number": ""
  },
  "body": {
    "db_date": "date",
    "db_timestamp": "timestamp(6)",
    "db_timestamp_with_local_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with local time zone",
    "db_char": "char",
    "db_float": "float",
    "db_nchar": "nchar",
    "db_nvarchar2": "nvarchar2",
    "db_varchar2": "varchar2",
    "db_binary_float": "binary_float",
    "db_binary_double": "binary_double",
    "db_timestamp_with_time_zone": "timestamp(6) with time zone",
    "db_interval_year_to_month": "interval year(2) to month",
    "db_interval_day_to_second": "interval day(2) to second(6)",
    "db_long": "long",
    "db_blob": "blob",
    "db_clob": "clob",
    "db_boolean": "char"
  }
}
```

Please help me with correct JQ that will work in jqplay.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slight bit of reform, it could be written as below. The key is to reuse the variable `$k` once for forming the key name and then later to exclude it from the members.

```
.body.primarykey[] as $k | 
{ 
  parameters: {($k): "" }, 
  body: (.body.members | map(select(.name != $k) | {(.name): .type | ascii_downcase}) | add)
}
```

jqplay - https://jqplay.org/s/hdTpOhvZ0I2

Comment: Hi @Inian, I want just one another modification in JQ that you provided. I want to fetch type of primarykey matching record into parameters before removing it from body. 

For Example -

     "parameters": {
     "db_number": "number"
      }

If its possible, please provide working JQ in JQPlay.

Comment: The two questions are not related, please ask a new question in the jq tag with a minimal sample JSON